# How to separate string and save in the array in asp.net

Tags: c#, regex

I have got column in db which saves the string as 1,2,3,4,5
I want to separate the string to 1 2 3 4 5 and save each number in the array , for instance the array should be like int [] numbers , int[0] = 1 , int[1] = 2 ......

Comment: Which aspect of this question do you consider to be specific to ASP.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want:

```
int[] array = text.Split(',')
                  .Select(x => int.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                  .ToArray();
```

Obviously this will go bang if any of the split results is not a parsable integer.

(You may also want to use a `List<int>` instead of an array, as a generally more flexible collection type.)

EDIT: Short but complete demo program:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string eventIds = "1,2,3";
        int[] array =
            eventIds.Split(',')
                    .Select(x => int.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    .ToArray();
        foreach (int id in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried ur code with no success , the array is null , the values which i passed was 1,2,3

Comment: string EventIds = voucher.EventIDs;
            int[] array = EventIds.Split(',')
                  .Select(x => int.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                  .ToArray();

Comment: @Mr A: That code will *never* return a null reference. It's hard to say exactly what you're doing wrong, but I'll edit my answer with a short but complete program demonstrating it working.

Answer (score 1):

here is code

```
Dim str as String = "1,2,3,4,5"

dim objstr() as String = str.split(",")
```

here split return array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "safer" version of John's excellent code snippet that will deal with values that cannot be parsed as `int` by adding them as `0`:

```
int temp;
int[] array = text.Split(',')
    .Select(x => int.TryParse(x, out temp) ? temp : 0)
    .ToArray();
```

If you want to be totally safe and discard any values that cannot be converted to an integer then you could use a function like this:

```
private static int[] ConvertTextToIntArray(string text)
{
    var integerList = new List<int>();
    var values = text.Split(',');
    int temp;

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(value, out temp))
        {
            integerList.Add(temp);
        }
    }

    return integerList.ToArray();
}
```