# How can we filter text value from string

Tags: asp.net

I need single different string value from my resulted string.

My string variable return value like:

```
string result = "1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1";    //  from here I'll need  2

or string result = "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1";    //  from here I'll need  4

or string result = "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1";     //  from here I'll need  3
```

Comment: replace all comman and 1 with "" you will get your string

Comment: change the string to array!! with asp functions! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941524/how-to-separate-string-and-save-in-the-array-in-asp-net

Comment: Are you using linq? And what is the actual rule for you to pick the value? You just want to ignore all the 1's and pick the non 1 value or you want to pick the maximum value from the result?

Comment: Thanks Amit ! I got your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var finalValue = result.Replace(",","").Replace("1","");
```

Comment: Thanks.  Its Mine answer! Also thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace coma(,) and 1 with blank('').

```
string single_value = result.Replace(",","").Replace("1","");
```

Comment: String does not have property `Text`

Comment: aah.. sorry.. code Updated..:)

Comment: No probs! And actually you don't need to have two variable for this you can just do it in one statement `string finalResult = result.Replace(",","").Replace("1","");`

Comment: If there is more than one non-1 value (the OP didn't specify), then they will be joined together.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the value that never appears more than once try the below code

```
 string result = "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1";    
 var UniqueElement = result.GroupBy(x => x)
                                           .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                                           .Select(g => g.Key)
                                           .ToList();
                                           Console.WriteLine(UniqueElement[0]);
```

This will work even if you have different values other than '1'

Example:  ",1,1,1,1,2,2,2,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enumerable.Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx), Max() will return maximum char value from string. If your string consists of commas and numbers only, that will be the maximum number, result is char of course:

```
result.Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the value that occurs once than this will work.

```
var value = result.Split(',')
  .GroupBy(v => v)
  .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
  .First()
  .Key;
```